# Structures of subgroups of a finite abelian p-group

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

$\newcommand\la{\langle}\newcommand\ra{\rangle}$Let $G=\mathbb{Z}/p^{i_1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/p^{i_r}$ with $i_1\leq\ldots\leq i_r$ be a finite abelian $p$-group. Then there can be many choices of generators $\{x_1,\ldots,x_r\}$ such that the order of $x_j$ is $p^{i_j}$ and $G=\la x_1\ra\times\cdots\times \la x_r\ra$.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then $H$ is of the same form with less or equal number of factors.

Does there exist a choice of generators $\{x_1,\ldots,x_r\}$ of $G$ as above such that $H$ is a product of subgroups of $\la x_j\ra$?

If it is not true, is there an easy counterexample?

Comment: I've added the commutative algebra tag, as this might be a standard facts of f.g. modules over PIDs.

Comment: What about the subgroup of ${\mathbb Z}/2 \oplus {\mathbb Z}/8$ generated by $(1,2)$?

Comment: @Derek Holt: You are right, that is a counterexample. I must be getting old(er): I was thinking of the structure theorem for (quotients by)  subgroups of finitely generated free Abelian groups .

Comment: Holt's example is a counterexample. Then where was Robinson confused? Is it related to the condition of generating set that I made?

Comment: I have to confess that when I was very much younger than I am now I made the same mistake and asserted somewhere (I think in a lecture to students) that the answer to this question is yes and easily proved. Fortunately a bright student found a counterexample, which explains why I remember it!

Comment: @DerekHolt would you post an answer with this nice short answer?

Comment: @YJKim : I explained my mistaken thinking in my response to Derek Holt above.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $G$ =  ${\mathbb Z}/2 \oplus {\mathbb Z}/8$, and let $H$ be the cyclic subgroup of order $4$ generated by the element $h = (\bar{1},\bar{2})$.

There is no element $g \in G$ with $2g = h$, and so $H$ cannot be a subgroup of a cyclic direct summand of $G$ of order $8$. And clearly it cannout be a subgroup of a summand of order $2$, so the answer to the question is no, and this is a counterexample.

Comment: After first seeing the question, I thought that surely the Smith normal form somehow gives you a positive answer. Which is wrong, as this answer shows.

Comment: @spin : I made that error in my (now deleted) comment.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your easy and clear example!